# Is it normal for it to take more than 3 weeks to get used to astigmatism correcting glasses?

Tags: eye, optometry, glasses, astigmatism

Is it common or realistic in the optometry industry to suggest to someone that it may take 6 weeks to adjust to new glasses?

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE! [For a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/8212), we can not, and will not, give personal medical advice. If you have a question regarding your personal health, you should see a doctor. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [How To Ask](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [meta]. [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question) explains question closure.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thanks Carey, I updated my answer to not ask for personal medical advice.

Comment: The only way you could meet site requirements would be to delete everything but the last paragraph.

Comment: @CareyGregory Ok, I've deleted everything but the last paragraph, in order to meet site requirements.

Comment: Thank you. Close and downvote retracted. I can't promise you'll get a good answer but now it will survive and your question didn't really change at all.

Comment: @CareyGregor  Thanks Carey